# Specific type of caesar cipher?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I am searching the name for this cipher algorithm:

It takes every character, starts with index = 0, and shifts it to right. After each character it increases the index.

For example, it takes the text **ABC** and translates it to **ACE**.

This algorithm has a specific name. Does anyone know it?

Comment: It's a sub-case of Vigenere cipher.  Wrong place to ask though, StackOverflow is about programming.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but it may be useful to your search: The generic name is substitution cypher; that includes Caesar, Vigenere, and Enigma.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is called a progressive Caesar(shifting) cypher.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), which is a sequence of Caesar ciphers, each with a different shift, in your case 26 ciphers with shifts 1,2,3...,26=0